# If $A,B,C,$ and $D$ are $4$ matrices and $AB=CD$, then will $B=A^{-1}CD$ or $B=CDA^{-1}$?

Tags: matrices

I was searching for the relationship between basis vectors of cylindrical and spherical co-ordinates. I used Cartesian co-ordinates so that they can be expressed in both of them and equate their values and I fell into this trap.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Multiply both sides of $AB=CD$ by $A^{-1}$ on the left to get $A^{-1}(AB)=A^{-1}CD$, which simplifies to $B=A^{-1}CD$

Comment: Thank you Sir!!

Comment: Look at the associativity of the multiplication and to properties of the identity matrix. YES is the answer to your two questions.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is associative but not generally commutative.

Given $AB=CD$, left-multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ to get $A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}CD$.

$A^{-1}A=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, so $A^{-1}AB$ is $B$, and we have $B=A^{-1}CD$.

(Right-multiplying by $A^{-1}$ would yield $ABA^{-1}=CDA^{-1},$

but $ABA^{-1}$ is not generally the same as $B$.)